# Two circles with two common outer tangents have same chords

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

Let $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ be two circles, $r_1 < r_2$, they have two common outer tangents, let $A$ and $B$ - common points of first outer tangent and $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ respectively, $C$ and $D$ - common points of second outer tangent, $E$ and $F$ are common points of line $BC$ and  $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ respectively. Prove, that $EC = BF$.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You have D pulling two jobs.... As a part to the segment CD tangent to both circles and as a point on line C.  Which is it?  Perhaps you can mark up your figure.

Comment: Please place the points A, B, etc on your figure.

Comment: @Jens, I did it

Comment: 'Common points of line $AC$' should likely be changed to common points of line $BC$, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: equal chords in circles with common tangents]
Join centers $G$ and $H$.  Since $ABHG$ and $CDHG$ are congruent trapezoids, then tangents $AB$ and $CD$ are equal.

But $AB^2=BE\cdot BC$, and $CD^2=CF\cdot CB$ [Euclid III, 36].

Therefore,$$BE\cdot BC=CF\cdot CB$$and$$\frac{BE}{CB}=\frac{CF}{BC}$$making$$BE=CF$$Therefore$$CE=BF$$

Comment: In case there's someone who doesn't know Euclid's Elements by heart, [see here](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII36.html).